# Does Terraform continue to have access to my AWS

Tags: terraform

If the AWS architecture was built by Terraform, does the software continue to have access to make changes or delete instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Terraform uses the credentials to connect and interact with the AWS API, but only has access during the Terraform run, not afterwards.

You could even give API credentials to developers to create instances, then revoke the credentials afterwards to ensure that they can't have continued access to the API with Terraform.

Answer (score 1):

The question is rather misguided. If you're afraid that the credentials you used with a piece of software may be dangerous revoke them. Even if Terraform normally doesn't store them they may be hardcoded in the configuration and that configuration can be leaked.